# What is a "maximal" object?

Tags: graph-theory

The idea of a "maximal" graph was introduced in a proof for Ore's Condition.
I didn't quite get the idea, and I would like more detailed explanations.

The theorem and proof are as follows.

Suppose G is a graph with v vertices ($v \ge 3$), and for every pair of non adjacent vertices $x$ and $y$, $\deg(x)+\deg(y) \ge v$ then G is hamiltonian.

Proof: Suppose the theorem is not true. We can assume that all airs of nonadjacent vertices satisfy the given degree condition, and that if p and q are nonadjacent vertices then the graph formed by adding edge $pq$, denoted $G+pq$, will be hamiltonian (if not, then join $pq$ and use the new graph instead of $G$). We would say G is maximal for the condition.

Source: "Introduction to Combinatorics" P.167

From the "Suppose the theorem is not true", I expect the proof to say that the inequality is satisfied in $G$ but $G$ is not hamiltonian. How does this relate to $G+pq$ being hamiltonian?
Also, does the sentence inside the parentheses mean that I should keep joining nonadjacent vertices until I get a graph that is hamiltonian?
If this is the case, how can I be guaranteed that I can obtain a hamiltonian graph by this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in your first observation: When we say, suppose the theorem is wrong, we suppose that we have a graph $G$ fulfilling the degree condition without being Hamiltonian. We now add some assumptions, which can be made without loss (as we will show): Note that if we add an edge $pq$ to $G$ the degree condition given will be fulfilled for $G + pq$ also. So we will add edges to $G$ until we cannot add another edge to $G$ without making the new graph Hamiltonian. The graph we have constructed then has the following properties:

- $G$ fulfills the degree condition given
- $G$ is not Hamiltonian
- $G+pq$ is Hamiltonian for any edge $pq$ not in $G$

A graph with the third property is called "maximal non-Hamiltonian", because it cannot be made "bigger" without getting Hamiltonian.